# Java Mockito is hitting real method rather than using mocked method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, junit4

My mockito method is hitting the real method rather than invoking the mocked method. Your inputs will be helpful

Java code.

```
public class CheckUser {
    private final UserDao userDao;

    public CheckUser (final String domain){
        userDao = new UserDao(domain);
    }

    public IUser getExistingUser(){
            if (userDao == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("userDao is null");
            }
            IUser existingUser = userDao.getExistingUser();
            if (existingUser == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("ExistingUser is null");
            }
            return existingUser;
    }
}
```

This is my JUnit test code.

```
    @Test
    public void testExistingUser() {
        UserDao mockUserDao = mock(UserDao.class);
        when(mockUserDao.getExistingUser()).thenReturn(getExistingTestUser());
    }

    private UserDao getExistingTestUser(() {
        return ExistingUserImpl.Builder(). //withfield methods. build();
    }
```

I  am creating this mock object for only testing purpose. This just return the mocked MockedExistingUserImpl  object which is implemented by IUser.

```
public class MockedExistingUserImpl implements IUser {
    //fields
    //overriding getter methods for all fields
    //Builder for  ExistingUserImpl
}
```

When ever I call userDao.getExistingUser() in my code, I am expecting to return the mocked Existing user object but it is hitting the real method and failing the test due to domain connection. We don't establish a domain connection to run Junits. Any inputs are appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: "When ever I call userDao.getExistingUser() in my code" > could you also post the unit tests code that invoke this?

Comment: Is this a class for live use, or a class for testing? Because it appears to be a class for live use, with tests built into the class.

Comment: CheckUser is only the class for live use. Remaining are created for testing purpose

Comment: @DatNguyen Nguyen This is my Junit code
@ Test
public void testExistingUser(){
UserDao mockUserDao = mock(UserDao.class);
when(mockUserDao.getExistingUser()).thenReturn(getExistingTestUser());
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in broken 'Dependency injection' principle.

Don't use `new` operator - create UserDao at the level above and use injection.

```
public class CheckUser {
    private final UserDao userDao;

    public CheckUser (final UserDao usedDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    public IUser getExistingUser() {
        if (userDao == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("userDao is null");
        }
        IUser existingUser = userDao.getExistingUser();
        if (existingUser == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ExistingUser is null");
        }
        return existingUser;
    }
}
```

Now you can test your code in the following way:

```
@Test
public void testExistingUser() {
    UserDao mockUserDao = mock(UserDao.class);
    when(mockUserDao.getExistingUser()).thenReturn(getExistingTestUser());

    CheckUser checkUser = new CheckUser(mockUserDao);
    IUser iUser = checkUser.getExistingUser();

    // assertions here
}

private UserDao getExistingTestUser(() {
    return ExistingUserImpl.Builder(). //withfield methods. build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, This approach makes sense. Using new operator is a bad idea. This is working for me if I create my Junits in a separate java test class. But, I need to create the test plans using a parentTestplan class.  So, if I use it in my existing parent test plan, its failing. This is really frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to read a tutorial about Mockito and follow that. You make the typical mistake: you create a mock object, but then you don't do anything so that your production code uses that mocked object.

Just doing a *mock(YourClass)* doesn't magically change that *new()* in your production code to return a mocked instance.

You need to *inject* that mocked instance into the code under test. For example by using the @InjectMock annotation.

For a good intro, see https://www.baeldung.com/Mockito-annotations for example.

And note: as written right now, you will have a hard time to use Mockito for your tests. Due to the direct call to *new()*, you would need PowerMock(ito) to test it. So: learn how to use Mockito, and then rework your production code to be easily testable. (turning to PowerMock would be the wrong strategy).

Comment: Always recommend a move to constructor injection where applicable.

Comment: @chrylis That is debatable. Having telescoped constructors just for the sake of testing ... well: the real world solution might be to use *real* dependency injection, not based on an additional ctor, but well, a real dependency injection system.